# Using layout_gravity device size dependent

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout XML file with a linear layout. I want to set the gravity depending on the device size, but since it is the only value which is device dependent, I do not want to use an extra layout file. So this is my idea:

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="@attr/logo_gravity" # Should be screen size dependent
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

My value in values/dimens.xml

```
 <attr name="logo_gravity">@attr/center_start</attr>
```

and in sw600dp/dimens.xml

```
 <attr name="logo_gravity">@attr/center_horizontal</attr>
```

And finally my attrs.xml

```
  <item name="center_start" type="integer">800003</item>
  <item name="center_horizontal" type="integer">1</item>
```

The values are form [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_gravity) site.
But this does not seem to work, because the layout_gravity tag in the layout file does not seem to accept such attrs.
Any ideas?

Comment: You can create dimention value files for integers which will contain those values

Comment: I already tried to use integers instead of attr, but it seems to be not accepted in layout_gravity tag.
<integer name="logo_gravity">@attr/center_start</integer>

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how to do it in xml but programmatically may be this is the way.

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.ll_yourLinearLayout);
            if(isTablet()){
                linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            }else{
                linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            }
```

And to find is the device Tablet

```
private boolean isTablet() {

        Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();
        Class configClass = Configuration.class;
        boolean isTablet = false;
        boolean isTenInchTab = false;
        try {
            Field smallestWidthField = configClass.getDeclaredField("smallestScreenWidthDp");
            int smallestWidthValue = smallestWidthField.getInt(config);
            isTablet = smallestWidthValue >= 600;
            isTenInchTab = (isTablet && smallestWidthValue >= 720);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            int currentLayout = config.screenLayout & config.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK;
            isTablet = currentLayout >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE;
            isTenInchTab = (isTablet && currentLayout >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE);

        }
        return isTablet;
    }
```

And you can also set a boolean inside res/values

```
<bool name="isHandest">false</bool>
```

and

inside values-sw600dp, values-sw720dp and values-xlarge

and

```
<bool name="isHandest">true</bool>
```

and in your method

```
private boolean isTablet() {
    Resources res = getResources();
    return res.getBoolean(R.bool.enableQAurl);
}
```

All this code goes in your activity. Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to do this in XML.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="@dimen/logo_gravity" # Should be screen size dependent
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

My value in values/dimens.xml

```
<dimen name="logo_gravity">@dimen/center_start</dimen>
```

and in sw600dp/dimens.xml

```
<dimen name="logo_gravity">@dimen/center_horizontal</dimen>
```

And finally my attrs.xml

```
<item name="center_start" type="dimen">800003</item>
<item name="center_horizontal" type="dimen">1</item>
```